# Ayuda con select_related(),

Tags: django

Se que agrego un foreingKey en la TablaB y la TabalC puedo solucionar
rapidamente pero quiero saber  si hay  alguna  manera que  funcione y me
pinte el  precio en el html

```
class TablaA(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # mas campos...

class TablaB(models.Model):
    tabla_a = models.ForeignKey(TablaA)
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digitals=7,decimal_place=2) 
    # mas campos...

class TablaC(models.Model):
    tabla_a = models.ForeignKey(TablaA)
    cantidad = models.PositiveIntegralField()
    # mas campos...

 ### Esta es mi vista 
 def mat_sal_detall(request, id_sal):
    TablaC = get_object_or_404(TablaC.objects.select_related(), id = id_sal)
    ctx = {'TablaC':TablaC}
    return render(request, 'salida/salida_detalle.html', ctx)
```

#### Este es mi html_list  y aqui necesito poner el precio

"No Pone nada de Precio como si no existiera"

```
<td class="text-center">{{TablaC.TablaA.nombre}}</td> # Funciona
<td class="text-center">{{TablaC.TablaA.TablaB.precio}}</td> # No funciona
```

Comment: Tony, tal vez puedas poner los nombres reales de tus tablas para entender un poco cuáles son las relaciones entre ellas, de esta manera sería más fácil ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe una relación entre la TablaC y la TablaB. Tampoco entre la TablaA para llegar a la TablaB.

Tendrías que hacer una etiqueta personalizada por el que pases como parámetro la TablaA (Así como usas TablaC.TablaA).

Te dejo un ejemplo en la siguiente URL de **etiqueta personalizada**: [VER EJEMPLO](http://www.elwebmaster.com/general/creando-etiquetas-y-filtros-de-plantillas-en-django-framework)